# C# Centre a group of Points in a Graph

Tags: c#, math, graph

I have a navigation system for a game bot that uses X and Y co-ordinates for waypoints.  To understand how my character is moving, I have a simple drawing surface 1000 * 1000 on which I paint the path. Then I can hover my mouse over any node in the path and get it's details.

[image: Here's a typical path]

The code for converting co-ordinates like 60.75, 73.13 is to simply convert to ints.  That makes a ridiculously small image so I multiply by 10 but it's still not using the space available.

```
            foreach (Node spot in path)
            {
                Point point = new Point();
                point.X = Convert.ToInt32(spot.X * 10);
                point.Y = Convert.ToInt32(spot.Y * 10);
                NodeSpot dot = new NodeSpot()
                {
                    Name = spot.Name,
                    Location = point
                };
                drawingSurface1.Nodes.Add(dot);
            }
```

How can I make the path I draw centred on the drawing surface and use the full height or width so that I can get a clearer view?

Comment: I would guess, you have to find the min/max values of x and y. The point MinX / MinY is your relative Top/Left coordinate and your MaxX / MaxY is your relative Bottom/Right coordinate which must then be matched to your paint surface.

Comment: Would you like it to be centered / "filled" on x _and_ y ? That means it will be possibly extremely distorted or just in one dimension?

Comment: Good question Fildor.  I'd like it centered on the longest dimension.

Comment: Add a float Scale property to the drawing surface. Then when drawing, apply a [ScaleTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Also for hit-testing, descale the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<double> OldMinAndMax(List<Node> path)
        {
            List<double> retValues = new();
            path.Sort((x, y) => y.X.CompareTo(x.X));
            retValues.Add(path.LastOrDefault().X);
            retValues.Add( path.FirstOrDefault().X);
            
            path.Sort((x, y) => y.Y.CompareTo(x.Y));
            retValues.Add(path.LastOrDefault().Y);
            retValues.Add(path.FirstOrDefault().Y);
            
            return retValues;
        }

        int Rescale(double oldV, double oldMin, double oldMax, int newMin, int newMax)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(((oldV - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMin);
        }
```

Then I can call it just by:

```
            List<Node> path = await PathMaker();

            List<double> oldMinMax = OldMinAndMax(path);

            double oldMinX = oldMinMax[0];
            double oldMaxX = oldMinMax[1];
            double oldMinY = oldMinMax[2];
            double oldMaxY = oldMinMax[3];

            path.FirstOrDefault().Name = "First";
            path.LastOrDefault().Name = "Last";

            foreach (Node spot in path)
            {
                Point point = new Point();
                point.X = Rescale(spot.X, oldMinX, oldMaxX, 50, 950);
                point.Y = Rescale(spot.Y, oldMinY, oldMaxY, 50, 950);
```

It works perfectly. Thanks for the rescaling suggestion.